# Why does making the setting width: 100% for an unordered list put the right-hand border off the edge of the page?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

When I put `width: 100%` for my `ul`, its border flies off the edge of the page. I tried setting `margin-right: 2px` to see if that would make a difference, but to no avail. What I thought would happen is that the border would occupy the right edge of the screen, and setting the margin-right would bring it to the left, but this didn't work. Why does it behave this way?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #nav {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 2px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Local</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Politics</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the page here: http://www.noetherherenorthere.com/practice/2013-1-5-02.html.

---

**Answers**

- [Browsers use `box-sizing: content-box`; use border-box instead ~ setek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940990/2407870)
- [Choose a smaller percentage ~ Damien Black](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940970/2407870)
- [Use `width: auto` ~ Josiah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940988/2407870)

Comment: Just a note: I know that this page is incredibly simple. I just wanted to make as simple an example as I could so there wouldn't be any distracting details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the box is being generated using the `content-box` model: with an explicit width, and then add border and padding to it.

And `ul`s have a left-padding by default, to account for the bullets.

Removing the left `padding` will stop this, but you won't be able to see the bullets anymore: you could always add a `margin` onto the `li`s to counteract this.

Alternatively, if you don't have to support older browsers (IE 6/7) you could use the property: `box-sizing: border-box;` which will cause the box to render by subtracting the padding and border from the explicit width, rather than adding to it like the `content-box` model.

**EDIT:** It's worth noting that IE 6 (and 7, I believe) will generate all boxes as if they were `border-box`es anyway. This causes inconsistencies when you start setting widths and applying padding in those browsers vs. modern browsers.

Comment: You guys all had really good answers - I wish I could choose all of you. After some thought, I decided the most fair thing would be to give the check to the most complete answer. I summarized your main points below my original question for anyone reading this in the future. If that is bad form, let me know and I might change it.

Answer (score 2):

Setting width to 100% does something a little odd in html, it makes the width 100% and the padding, border and margin will all appear outside of that full width.

You'll have to do less then 100% to leave room for the border and margin.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks. Is that true in all browsers, as far as you know? (I'm using Firefox, so I'd assume it is, if it's true in FF.)

Answer (score 1):

Using 100% will make the main box fill the whole screen, but padding and margin will be excluded. Instead of `width: 100%` use `width: auto`. That will make the box fit comfortably and takes into account margin and padding.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfWvr/